# Accordion inside list view does not start from top in Xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, scrollview, accordion

```
<StackLayout>
     <Listview>
      <ListView.header>
       <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
         <accordion:AccordionView>
          <accordion:AccordionView.Children>
           <accordion:AccordionItemView>
            <accordion:AccordionItemView.ItemContent>
                  AccordionItemView ItemContent #1
            </accordion:AccordionItemView.ItemContent>
            <accordion:AccordionItemView.ItemContent>
                  AccordionItemView ItemContent #2
            </accordion:AccordionItemView.ItemContent>
           </accordion:AccordionItemView>
          </accordion:AccordionView.Children>
         </accordion:AccordionView>
        </Grid>
       </StackLayout>
      </ListView.header>
     </Listview>
</StackLayout>
```

I have a list view which has an accordion view inside it.
I have set the accordion property KeepOnlyOneItemOpen="True", this works perfect.
When I open my first accordion view and scroll it down and then when I tap and open my other accordion element, the first one closes but the one that I intend to open does not start from the top but instead it starts from where the list view's scroll stopped.
I have not given any scroll view to my implementation as I have a list view.
I HAVE **NOT USED ANY SCROLLVIEW** in my code.

Comment: Can you please show us some relevant codes? We can help much without seeing the codes. It would be better if you can share us [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have edited my question with xaml code structure.

Comment: Well, the xaml code structure does not help much to find out the problem. You should check the click event when you open  a new accordion element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using listview, scrollview made it more simpler.
Hence removed listview and used scrollview inside grid and separate stacklayout.